# Diagonal reflection of an int array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to perform a diagonal reflection on an int array laid out in a board, reflecting around the diagonal descending from the left to the right. This is an attempt to "flip a chess board around" while working with the [N queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle).

- The array is displayed as on a board whose size is `n*n`
- The length of the array is `n`
- The index of the array represents the row (i.e `arr[0]` means the top row)
- The value at the index represents the horizontal placement of the Queen (i.e `arr[2] = 3;` would mean "Place a queen at column 4 on row 3" (zero-based index))

Example

```
int[] matrix = {0,2,4,1,3};
```

would be displayed as

```
[Q x x x x]
[x x Q x x]
[x x x x Q]
[x Q x x x]
[x x x Q x]
```

After running the command

```
matrix = diagonalReflection(matrix);
```

The matrix should look like this (note, the reflection is based on the descending diagonal)

```
[Q x x x x]
[x x x Q x]
[x Q x x x]
[x x x x Q]
[x x Q x x]
```

How would I go about to swap the elements accordingly to achieve this result?

**Update:**
I have tried problably 5-10 different ways, but this is the one I'm using so far:

```
public static Board diagonalReflection(Board src){

    int n = src.size();
    Board dest = new Board(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        dest.set(src.get(i), i);

    return dest;
}
```

Function note:

```
Board.get(x) means "return arr[x]"
Board.set(x, y) means "arr[x] = y"
```

Comment: Please show us your tries (code, pseudo code)

Comment: You have a working solution. What's the problem that you see with it?

Comment: I thought it worked as well, until I attempted to manually change the location of a single queen, then reflect it again. The outcome was incorrect, which was kind of weird. Should I assume the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: Well, if I were doing this, I'd keep the queen-array as it is, & simply move the board, ie no change in position of queen, but simply move the entire board, ie keep doing the transpose of n*n board matrix. As far as I know, moving the board wont affect the already placed-queen position at all.that way, you wont get errors in queen position.

Comment: @krystah "I attempted to manually change the location of a single queen" That is very likely the problem. You cannot manually change position of a *single* queen and keep your `matrix` a permutation. You need to change at least two queens to maintain the permutation property.

Comment: The diagonal reflection shouldn't care about the placements (and collisions) of the queens, it should merely "flip the board". When I said I got an incorrect outcome, I was not referring to queen collisions, but that the queens weren't moved the way I expected them to with the for loop. Every queen except the one on the row I moved, did though.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `int[] matrix` variable is a permutation, you could build a reflection with a simple `for` loop, like this:

```
int[] reflected = new int[matrix.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != matrix.length ; i++) {
    reflected[matrix[i]] = i;
}
```

Running this loop on your sample `matrix` produces the expected

```
{0, 3, 1, 4, 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you intend to generate, is called transpose of the matrix.
Mathematically, you do that by swapping rows & columns, so

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

becomes

```
[1 4 7]
[2 5 8]
[3 6 9]
```

Program-wise, logic would be:

```
new_matrix[i][j]=old_matrix[j][i];
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen ways to do it with 2d-arrays, but I needed to make this work with a flat int-array!

Comment: I think the problem lies in the fact that when doing with flat int array, suppose you are on i th row, so the algorithm assumes that i-1 rows are already covered.However, when you move the board(ie change queen positions) it may happen that a row i may have a queen, but a row j<i would be empty due to the board movement.That might mess up the algorithm.

Comment: A solution to this would be to use 2 flat int arrays, original_array & display_array. original_array would compute normally like the n-queen does, while display_array would do the required rotations & then display the original_array accordingly.Here, no of rotations would be directly dependent on the row no where the queen is to be placed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, I think this is what you want:

```
public int[] diagonalReflexion(int[] matrix) {
  int[] result = new int[matrix.length];
  for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    result[matrix[i]] = i;
  }
  return result;
}
```